# installing yesod on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, yesod

I want to install yesod on windows 7 64 bits. It fails on the network package. This is what I've done:
I purged ghc and all packages and reinstalled the haskell platform. 
Then I updated cabal which worked. The new cabal.exe is not in the path and the systems keeps using the old version. 
I added the path to the new cabal.exe and erased the old version. Same issue with alex and happy.
Then I installed yesod-platform and yesod-bin. It failed on the network library (2.5.0.0). I installed mingw and msys (for some reason the msys part of the haskell platform is ignored).
I installed network in Msys with the new version of cabal. Network 2.5.0.0. is installed. Then installed yesod-platform and yesod-bin again as in http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart. Okay... this works fine.
Now I have yesod 1.2.6, ghc version 7.6.3 and cabal 1.20.0.3.
Started yesod init, used 'simple' and changed directory to the new project.
Then I did cabal sandbox init. No errors.
Then: cabal install --enable-tests . yesod-platform yesod-bin --max-backjumps=-1 --reorder-goals
.....
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
authenticate-1.3.2.8 depends on network-2.5.0.0 which failed to install.
conduit-extra-1.1.0.4 depends on network-2.5.0.0 which failed to install.
connection-0.2.1 depends on network-2.5.0.0 which failed to install.
....
I think the problem is that installing network works in msys, but not as part of yesod.
Any idea what could be wrong?

Kees

Comment: Can you try rerunning the command with the extra flag `--constraint network==2.4.1.2` and see what happens?

Comment: I got:
<lines with new to install packages> ....
cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
haskell-platform-2013.2.0.0
cgi-3001.1.7.5
HTTP-4000.2.8
Use --force-reinstalls if you want to install anyway.

Comment: Please paste the full output somewhere else and provide a link?

Comment: http://www.tbsoftware.nl/testYesod/log.txt

Comment: Alright, give one more try: `cabal install yesod-platform yesod-bin haskell-platform --max-backjumps=-1 --reorder-goals`

Comment: That failed quickly: cabal: There is no package named 'haskell-platform'.
You may need to run 'cabal update' to get the latest list of available packages. I did cabal update, but no difference.

Comment: Alright, then you have to go the tedious approach: `cabal install yesod-platform yesod-bin --constraint parsec==3.1.3 --constraint network==2.4.1.2`. I'm not even sure if *that* will completely solve it. You may just have to use MSys when inside your sandbox.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. But it still fails.  
How is it possible that the out of the box installation of ghc (haskell-platform) needs so much tinkering to get things going? Is it yesod or the age of the haskell platform?

The errormessage:
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
fsnotify-0.1.0.2 depends on system-fileio-0.3.13 which failed to install.
hamlet-1.2.0 depends on system-fileio-0.3.13 which failed to install.
project-template-0.1.4.1 depends on system-fileio-0.3.13 which failed to install... and other packages that need fileio-0.3.13

Comment: At this point, I'd recommend moving this discussion to the mailing list or issue tracker. I'll definitely need more info on those last failures, as they're outside of the packages the yesod team maintains.